# Dynamically generated delete button does not respond to an OnclickListener(Android JAVA)

Tags: java, android, xml

I created an app that dynamically adds an edittext field to the view by clicking an Add button and deletes it by clicking a delete button. I created a separate xml file called field.xml that is called up when a new edittext field is added to the view. But the delete button does not remove this edittext field when clicked. What am I missing in the code I have tried most options but to no avail.

Here is the main java file

SchoolSearchSetup.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class SchoolSearchSetup extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private EditText searchSchoolID;
    private Button searchSchoolButtonID;
    private ListView listOfSchoolsID;
    private Button  openNewschoolID;
    private LinearLayout schoolSetupLayout;
    private Button addNewClass;
    private EditText classNameEditText;
    private Button deleteButton;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_school_search_setup);

        findAllViewsID();
        initializeListenners();
    }

    public void findAllViewsID(){

        classNameEditText = findViewById(R.id.classNameText);
        addNewClass = findViewById(R.id.addNewClassButton);
        schoolSetupLayout = findViewById(R.id.schoolSetupLayout);
        searchSchoolID = findViewById(R.id.searchSchoolID);
        searchSchoolButtonID = findViewById(R.id.searchSchoolButtonID);
        listOfSchoolsID = findViewById(R.id.listOfSchoolsID);
        openNewschoolID = findViewById(R.id.openNewschoolID);
        deleteButton = findViewById(R.id.delete_button);




    }

    public void initializeListenners(){
        openNewschoolID.setOnClickListener(SchoolSearchSetup.this);
        addNewClass.setOnClickListener(SchoolSearchSetup.this);
        deleteButton.setOnClickListener(SchoolSearchSetup.this);


    }




    public void addNewClass(){

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.field, null);

        schoolSetupLayout.addView(rowView, schoolSetupLayout.getChildCount() -1);


    }




    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        switch(view.getId()){

            case R.id.openNewschoolID:

              displaySchoolSetUpForms();

              break;

           case R.id.addNewClassButton:

               addNewClass();

               break;

            case R.id.delete_button:

                schoolSetupLayout.removeView((View) view.getParent());


        }

    }


    private void displaySchoolSetUpForms() {

        schoolSetupLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }



}
```

The main XML file

activity.school_search_setup.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context="com.example.demeainc.demea.MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/backgroundColor">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/backArrowClassView"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_class"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>


    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                    android:text="Search your school."
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="25dp" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:layout_width="300dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp">
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/searchSchoolID"
                    android:layout_width="270dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp"
                    android:hint="Search"/>

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/searchSchoolButtonID"
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
                    android:text="Search"
                    android:textColor="#ffff"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="300dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ListView
                        android:id="@+id/listOfSchoolsID"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="80dp"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:cacheColorHint="@color/ligtherDarkGrey"
                        android:divider="#CCCCCC"
                        android:dividerHeight="2dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="2dp" >
                    </ListView>


                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>



            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/openNewschoolID"
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:text="Open New School"
                    android:textColor="#ffff"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/schoolSetupLayout"

                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/schoolSetupText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="School Setup"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"/>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/classNameText"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="5"
                        android:hint="Class name, e.g Grade one" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/delete_button"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@android:drawable/ic_delete"/>


                </LinearLayout>


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_gravity="center">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/addNewClassButton"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:text="Add new class"
                        android:textColor="#ffff"
                        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/nextButton"
                        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:text="Next"
                        android:textColor="#ffff"
                        android:background="@color/green"/>

                </LinearLayout>


            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>



    </ScrollView>


</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the Field.xml file for the edit text to be added. Both the field.xml and the activity.school_search_setup.xml share the same IDs.

Field.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/schoolSetupLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/classNameText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:hint="Class name, e.g Grade one" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/delete_button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:drawable/ic_delete"/>


</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You have two delete buttons. One in the `activity_main.xml` and the other in `Field.xml`. Which one are you trying to implement for deleting the view?

Comment: Ok @Napster. The delete button in the fields. XML file. It is.

Comment: So you need to put an `onClickListener` on that delete button. The `R.id.delete_button` in your case is the other main delete button

Comment: Moreover you should never share Ids. They should always be unique

Comment: In `addNewClass()` function, below `View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.field, null);` add this line `rowView.findViewById(R.id.delete_button).setOnClickListener(SchoolSearchSetup.this);`

Comment: Hello @Napster thank for this answer but I have tried this but it still does not work. I think the problem could be around this [schoolSetupLayout.removeView((View) view.getParent())] apecifically in the getParent() method. I might be doing something wrong here but can't figure it out. what do you think

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using

```
setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

**Update:**
Try this code block:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
Button btn = new Button(this);
btn.setId(i);
final int id_ = btn.getId();
btn.setText("button " + id_);
btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(80, 80, 90));
linear.addView(btn, params);
btn1 = ((Button) findViewById(id_));
btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),
                "Button clicked index = " + id_, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks @SaswataRoy. This gets to remove all vies instead of the specifics required.One view at a time.

Comment: you have to call this method on the corresponding button object .. I hope you are maintaining the ids properly even if the button is generated dynamically

Comment: How to you get IDs of dynamically generated views. how will I implement this method in all button object. I am using one onclick method. I am still new to android development and Java in general. pls pardon me @SaswataRoy